# How would I assign the prototype of Base to User?

Tags: javascript, prototype, appcelerator, commonjs

I'm trying to have a *Base* object that has some common methods (save, update, etc). I've tried using `Object.create(Base)`, but could not figure out how to get it to work with `module.exports`.

## How would I assign Base as the prototype of User? Or is there a better way to accomplish my goals?

### models/user.js

```
var Base = require('models/base.js');

var User = module.exports = function(data) {    
    data       = data || {};    
    this.fname = data.fname || '';
    this.lname = data.lname || '';
    this.email = data.email || '';    
};

/**
 * Takes a response from FB and convert it to object
 */
User.prototype.importFacebookData = function(result) {

    this.fname      = result.first_name || '';
    this.lname      = result.last_name || '';
    this.name       = result.name || this.fname + ' ' + this.lname || '';
    this.email      = result.email || '';    
};
```

### models/base.js

```
var Base = module.exports = function() {

};

Base.prototype.save = function() {
  // Some code for saving to DB
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
User.prototype = new Base();
```

Not at a machine I can test it on right now, but theoretically that should work.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome one liner. Now I feel really dumb that it was so easy.

Comment: Meh, no problem. I've had to ask why X isn't working and then was asked "why do you have brackets around it if it's not supposed to be an array?". We all have those moments.